# ExtJS Components Reusability

Tags: extjs4, reusability

Can any one tell me that how can we achieve the re usability concept in ExtJS 4? I have a page where I have 4 bar chart and for that I had to write same code 4 times. How to make it generic so that we can call one function which will take different parameters and that one function will create a chart depending on what inputs I had provided to the function.

Is there any example for that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of information about writing classes. Look at any of the MVC examples.

A custom class:

```
Ext.define('MyClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.html += 'Foo';
        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    new MyClass({
        renderTo: document.body,
        html: 'X'
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't there be more simpler example than this

Comment: Updated OP with a simpler example.

Comment: I am trying to make a custom function drawCombo in my class but it is giving error however if i change drawCombo to initComponent it reneders fine

Comment: Ext.define('MyClass',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
 drawCombo: function(){
  //combo box code goes here
    }
});

Comment: and calling it like this 

Ext.onReady(function () {

 var class1 = new MyClass();
 class1.drawCombo();
});

Comment: If you can give me a simple example which create a function to create a combo box  ?